# $_GET in uploading image

Tags: javascript, php

my code is working if I use $_SESSION but I need to name the file what is in the URL. 
this is the sample URL: localhost/boldr/updateimage.php?EMPLOYEE_ID=180627-027
I want to rename the uploaded image like profile180627-027 but it's not working in $_GET.

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['EMPLOYEE_ID'];


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.',$fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');


if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
  if($fileError == 0){
    if($fileSize < 1000000){
      $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
      $fileDestination = 'img/'.$fileNameNew;
      move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

      $sql = "UPDATE employees SET image=0 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='$id'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      header("Location: updateimage.php?EMPLOYEE_ID=$id");
    }else{
      echo "Your file is to big";
  }
}else{
  echo  "There was an error!";
}
}else{
  echo "You cannot upload files of this file";
}
}

 echo "<form action='updateimage.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form- 
 data'>
 <input type='file' name='file'>
 <button type='submit' name='submit'>Upload</button>
 </form>";

 ?>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @AdamMcGurk no error message, after i clicked the button the url show only 127.0.0.1/boldr/updateimage.php?EMPLOYEE_ID=

Comment: OK. So I'm confused. What is updateimage.php?? Is that the code here? Because I see nowhere where the url would be set to have the ID in it. Just because you set the $_GET superglobal, doesnt mean it will go into the url

Comment: AdamMcGurk yea the updateimage.php is the code below. how do i set it not globaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying this in your form part:
action='updateimage.php?EMPLOYEE_ID=$id'

Comment: thank you. its working. you're my savior i stuck here in 4days and now i can go to next function thank you again.

Comment: @Kazz other's spend time for making you happy and solve your problem! respect their time and mark the answer that works as accepted!

Comment: ohh sorry,@AdamMcGurk for late mark. thank you again sir.